# Разместить String,String в лист

Tags: java, android, listview

Требуется разместить

```
languagesMap.put("Afrikaans", "af");
languagesMap.put("Albanian", "sq");
languagesMap.put("Amharic", "am");
languagesMap.put("Arabic", "ar");
languagesMap.put("Armenian", "hy");
languagesMap.put("Azeerbaijani", "az");
languagesMap.put("Basque", "eu");
languagesMap.put("Belarusian", "be");
languagesMap.put("Bengali", "bn");
languagesMap.put("Bosnian", "bs");
```

В `ListView`, изначально была попытка эти данные разместить в `HashMap`. Но потом эту карту в лист закинуть не удалось.

Comment: не получилось, потому, что нужно было делать так: `List<HashMap<String, String>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` может хранить только один объект в ячейке. Если вам надо несколько, то создайте класс, хранящий эти значения и его экземпляры используйте в `List`.

```
public class MyClass {
    public String str1;
    public String str2;

    public MyClass(String str1, String str2) {
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str1 = str1;
    }
}
```

И вот так теперь в `List`:

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new MyClass("Arabic", "ar"));
list.add(new MyClass("Afrikaans", "af"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.put("A", "A1");
map.put("B", "B1");
final List<ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(map));
map = list.get(0);
System.out.println(map.get("A")); //A1
```